# Google Plus One Button - How to add a callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-plus

I have the google+ button being rendered on my site as follows:

In the JS:

```
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
```

In the html:

```
<g:plusone size="medium" href="https://site.com"></g:plusone>
```

How can I add a callback to this to detect when the user has clicked? I see the docs here: https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#jsapi not seeing how to implement with the current render. Thanks

Comment: Did you notice the "callback" property of the parameter object?  I think that's what you want.

Comment: @Pointy where would that be added?

Comment: You set it in the tag: `<g:plusone callback='functionName' ...>`

Comment: Thanks, tried that but it doesn't ever take effect... <g:plusone size="medium" href="https://site.com" callback="alert('gotime')"></g:plusone>

Comment: I think the callback argument should just be the **name** of a global function. It's hard to tell from that documentation however.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a JavaScript callback using a callback attribute to your +1 button markup. Supply the name of a function that resides in the global namespace. It will be called when a user clicks on the +1 button.

Here's what your code might look like:

```
<script>

   function myCallback(jsonParam) {

      alert("URL: " + jsonParam.href + " state: " + jsonParam.state);

   }

</script>

<g:plusone size="medium" href="https://site.com" callback="myCallback"></g:plusone>
```

You can learn more about this attribute in the [tag parameters section of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#plusonetag-parameters).

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does the callback work? i.e. how does javascript in parent window get access child window (Google Oauth)'s state?

Comment: Posted above question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934815/how-does-google-plus-oauth-callback-function-work

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Jenny's answer you can also use a **HTML5-valid** +1 tag by setting the class attribute to g-plusone, and prefixing any button attributes with data- such as callback

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-callback="myCallback" ></div>
```

From https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/