# Attach a click() event to the google plus button?

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I'd like to add a alert message on the page when a user clicks 'g+' button. how can i achieve this ? 
here is code :

```
<g:plusone href="http://test.com//" annotation="inline" width="300"></g:plusone> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 (function() { 
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: Please read up on how to post code in code blocks. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Plus One Button - How to add a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107221/google-plus-one-button-how-to-add-a-callback)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just incase you want some code to get you started, the following markup will enable the interaction events in a +1 button:

```
<div
  class="g-plusone"
  data-expandto="bottom"
  data-onendinteraction="onEnded"
  data-onstartinteraction="onStarted"
  data-recommendations="false"
  data-annotation="inline"
  data-height="25"
  data-autoclose="true"
  data-callback="onCallback" 
  data-width="300"
>
```

The following code will handle the events:

```
function onStarted(args){
  console.log("started");
  console.log(args);
}
function onEnded(args){
  console.log("ended");
  console.log(args);
}
function onCallback(args){
  console.log("callback");
  console.log(args);
}
```

The callback will return the +1 state of the button, start/end interaction indicates the user state. You can see a demo of all the events [here](http://wheresgus.com/hidepopup.html).

Comment: very good solution thanks...
Is there any way to get current logged-in user already did g+..

Comment: The event for the callback only gets raised when the button is clicked but the args.state parameter will either be "on" or "off" in the callback when the interaction happens. So, you will not be able to determine this when the user comes back to the page... unless they unclick the +1. What are you trying to do by seeing whether they are +1'd?

Answer (score 2):

Try reading their documentation which is actually quite good. They provide access to a callback function. See the section `tag attributes`.

https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#script-parameters

Comment: No problem. Here is a link to another SO question where they answer how to use the callback (in case you aren't familiar with JSON). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107221/google-plus-one-button-how-to-add-a-callback

Comment: OK , actually i am developing a script that don't show plus button if the logged in user already clicked to g+ button ie already share otherwise google plus button will appear.