# Capture Google+ Button click event

Tags: jquery, google-plus, jquery-events

**Edit:** See JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/VW4ea/

I'm trying to capture the click event of the Google+ Button. However this is proving a little more difficult than expected.

Here is the function:

```
function myCallback(){
  console.log("callback");
}
```

After reading this post: [Google Plus One Button - How to add a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107221/google-plus-one-button-how-to-add-a-callback) I added:

```
data-callback="myCallback"
```

to the g+ button but it still isn't working.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise I had to click the bounty. I thought that it was automatic :/ Done now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your jsFiddle isn't looking for javascript calls in the HTML.

Change `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <body>` in the drop down to the left and it works just fine

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VW4ea/1/)

Comment: ok, it works in your JSFiddle example, however when I implement it on this page: http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-apply-distortions-to-a-uiimage-using-opengl-es/ click the G+ button where it says "To download the resource files available with this tutorial, please click one of the following buttons:" in the green box and it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the script is being reached? If not, place an alert before the function to check. My guess is that your js is misplaced in your HTML. It is a lot harder for us to help on actual sites because we don't have direct access to the files

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the function to be called script above the button.