# How does Google Plus Oauth callback function work?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth

In Google+ JS documentation, it says that if a callback function parameter is specified, Google will call that function when auth flow completes.

How would that work? i.e. how does javascript in parent window get access child window (Google Oauth)'s state?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript children windows can call functions in their parent windows. Let's say you specify the function `signinCallback(authResult)`, then the auth window can call `parent.signinCallback(authResult)` to pass `authResult` to your main window.